# What does it mean to say 'turning cold calls into warm prospects'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

[image: Source]

Also I believe that is grammatical mistake, shouldn't it be-

1 *He says, after the deal concludes,*

2 *He said, after the deal concluded,*-?

Answer (score 2):

When a salesperson calls someone without the person knowing or asking about it, it's called a 'cold call'. Essentially, an unsolicited phone call. 
So in this excerpt, the salespeople referenced are saying that by using Microsoft's Dynamics program, they are better equipped and prepared to convince customers to buy their products. These are of course 'warm prospects' for them, situations of high hopefulness for the future.

Also, I don't know about the exact context of this extract, but it seems grammatically correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.

> Mr. Weiner said that, after the deal concludes, salespeople [...]

We need more context, but one possibility is that Mr. Weiner is referring to a deal that is in progress at the moment. This deal might be for the acquisition of this product, Microsoft's *Dynamics*. So, after the deal is completed, the salespeople will be able to have more information on potential clients by using *Dynamics*.

Another interpretation is that they already have the product  *Dynamics* and the salespeople use. Mr. Weiner says that after the deal concludes (any deal that  salespeople are working on),  the salespeople will be able to refer to the product for more information on potential customers.

> [cold call](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cold+call)
>   A telephone call or visit made to someone who is not known or not expecting contact, often in order to sell something.

I think it's referred to as *cold* because the caller has not established any kind of contact or relationship before this call, a *cold relationship*. This is opposite to a *warm call*.

> [warm call](http://sales.about.com/od/glossaryofsalesterms/g/What-Is-Cold-Calling.htm)
>   If you are calling prospects who have already shown an interest in your products, such as a prospect who fills out a postcard or website request for information, then it's referred to as 'warm calling.'

However, I do not believe that *warm prospect* refers to *warm calling*. A *warm prospect* seems to mean that instead of making a cold call with **no** information about the potential client, by using *Dynamics*, you will be making a cold call with **some** (or even a lot) of information on the client. By having more information on the client, this gives you an advantage when you are making a deal with the client. So, the call turns from a "cold prospect" (very little chance of success) to a "warm prospect" (higher chance of success).